# Makefile which compresses javascript

Tags: javascript, makefile, jscompress

I want to compress javascript in yui compressor, 
How to write Make file for compress javascript.

Because grammar is difficult and does not understand it, 
Could you give me a sample Makefile for me?

Comment: I honestly don't know why anyone bothers with this anymore. Just serve your JS with gzip encoding and be done with it. Gzip will compress text very effectively.

Comment: Of course I expect the effect to transfer efficiency. In addition I expect the effect of the slight difficulty reading　my js codes.

Comment: @SpliFF: because minification makes gzip more efficient. It makes a difference if you're stuck with some large bloated JS framework...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your makefile would look something like

```
code.compressed.js: code.js
    compressor -o $@ $<
```

Note that the second line is indented with a *tab character*, not just spaces. The make utility cares about this.

`code.compressed.js` is the name that the file should be written to, `code.js` is the file to compress, and `compressor` is the program doing the compression.

The `-o` flag indicates the output file, following the convention of compilers and similar tools. Yours may differ; check its documentation.

The variable `$@` is Makefile shorthand for "this rule's target", `code.compressed.js` in this case. Similarly, `$<` is an abbreviation for "this rule's first dependency". These variables are useful so that you needn't repeat yourself, nor make duplicate changes when files get renamed.

If you have multiple files that will all be compressed into a single output file, you can put them all on the dependency line, and then use the special variable `$^` in the *build rule* to specify all of them:

```
code.compressed.js: code1.js code2.js
    compressor -o $@ $^
```

Alternately, if you want them each compressed separately, you can write a pattern rule and use it for all of them:

```
TARGETS = code1.cjs code2.cjs code3.cjs

all: $(TARGETS)

%.cjs: %.js
    compressor -o $@ $<
```

Make defaults to building the first target that it sees, which is `all` in this case. The list of files to compress to is given by the contents of the `TARGET` variable. The `%` is a wildcard that make will substitute to generate rules for matching source and target file names.

Comment: Thank you for a very plain answer. 
However, there are many source codes. 
How to make that case? code1.js,code2.js,,,

Comment: Please edit that expansion into your question, rather than leaving it in a comment.